# git repository with apache on ubuntu server only .git paths

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, git

I have an ubuntu server, running apache2. I'm trying to set it to serve git repository over http.

After reading tens of samples, I ended with very simplified config file, removing all of the authentication for simplicity.

My git_conf file in conf.d looks like this:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /srv/repos/git/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Location /git>
</Location>
```

I created an empty git repository like this:

```
# git --bare init myrepo
# cd myrepo
# git --bare update-server-info
# cd ..
# chown -R www-data:www-data myrepo
```

Now, the fun begins. I was able to clone the repo on the local machine:

```
# cd ~/tmp
# git clone /my/repo/path/myrepo test1
```

But, whenever I try to clone from a remote machine like this:

$ git clone http://myserver/git/myrepo test1

I receive:

```
fatal: http://cfs-int-redmine/git/iosdemo/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

If on the server I create a symlink to the repo like:

```
# ln -s myrepo myrepo.git
```

And then I try to clone http://myserver/git/myrepo.git, it works.

So, what's going on? Should I aways use ".git" in order to be able to use the repository? How do I make it to work without .git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically any hosting will use the `.git` suffix. From a technical standpoint I wouldn't have expected it to be required, but it's a pretty ingrained standard at this point, and your own testing seems to verify that `git` does enforce this. The `.git` suffix on the directory name marks the directory as a git bare repository, similar to how the `.git` folder is used to store the git repository info in a non-bare repository.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that it does not work. It works only with ".git". I understand the conventions, but I want to make it work w/o .git

Comment: @Sunny: You asked "Should I do this?" The short answer is yes, you should follow the convention. It seems like git-http-backend is enforcing this for you too. Sound like you'll have to go hacking in there if you really do want to get this working.

Comment: @Sunny: Another potential alternative (if you don't need anonymous access) is git/ssh/gitosis, which works really well together and doesn't have any file path requirements meaning you can check out over SSH from any folder on the server, including one without a `.git` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this problem is also making 100% sure that your *ScriptAlias* points to the correct *git-http-backend* location.

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /data/git/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
```